# Link a button to a part of <div> in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to create a simple quiz app, I am stuck on this problem I want to hide Question 2 when Question 1 is clicked, I tried linking the buttons to a , but that will not hide the question. I had linked button 2 to a different page but that does not seem to be the ideal solution as in the future the website will have multiple questions. I am trying to show just the question which is being clicked and not the whole thing. What should be the JavaScript code that goes with the buttons that will show only the required question

```js
function progress(timeleft, timetotal, $element) {
  var progressBarWidth = timeleft * $element.width() / timetotal;
  $element.find('div').animate({
    width: progressBarWidth
  }, 500).html(Math.floor(timeleft / 60) + ":" + timeleft % 60);
  if (timeleft > 0) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      progress(timeleft - 1, timetotal, $element);
    }, 1000);
  }
};
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#progressBar {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  height: 22px;
  background-color: #0A5F44;
}

#progressBar div {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0 10px;
  line-height: 22px;
  /* same as #progressBar height if we want text middle aligned */
  width: 0;
  background-color: #CBEA00;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Do not take in account */

html {
  padding-top: 30px
}

a.solink {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: #f3f5f6;
  color: #cfd6d9;
  border: 1px solid #cfd6d9;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all .3s;
  z-index: 999
}

a.solink::first-letter {
  text-transform: capitalize
}

a.solink:hover {
  color: #428bca
}


/* Create two unequal columns that floats next to each other */

.column {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}

.left {
  width: 75%;
  height: 100%;
}

.right {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* button */

.button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 2px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<div id="progressBar">
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>

<body>
  <script src="scripts.js">
  </script>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column left" style="background-color:#aaa;">
      <div id="first">
        <h2>Question 01</h2>
        <p>Full Form of HTML is "Hypertext Makrup Language"</p>
        <button onclick="truee()">True</button>
        <button onclick="falsee()">False</button>
      </div>
      <div id="second">
        <h2>Question 02</h2>
        <p>Full Form of HTML is "Hypertext Makrup Language"</p>
        <button onclick="truee()">True</button>
        <button onclick="falsee()">False</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column right" style="background-color:#bbb;">
      <h2>Questions</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="column right" style="background-color:#bbb;">
      <div>
        <a href="first"><button class="button">01</button></a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a href="second"><button class="button">02</button></a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button class="button">03</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button class="button">04</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button class="button">05</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button class="button">06</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button class="button">07</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button class="button">08</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I am trying to show just the question which is being clicked and not the whole thing, this is just a prototype

Comment: As @isherwood suggests, you can use the [edit] link under the question to add more information, it might not been seen in comments. You also need to add the javascript functions you are calling in your code (e.g. `truee` and `falsee` if they are what you consider a "click") Please see hoe to create a [MRE]

Comment: Nothing calls the one JavaScript function that's shown.  For the "questions that are clicked" most of them have no click handler, only 01 and 02 are links to other pages which don't exist in this example.  It's really not clear specifically what you're asking.

Comment: I have added a listener on the button but still couldn't figure out what javascript will hide the other questions. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Give each Question div a unique id & a class "hidden" which hides the div via css. On a button click remove the "hidden" class from the target div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give each Question div a unique id & a class "hidden" which hides the div via css. On a button click remove the "hidden" class from the target div.

```js
function progress(timeleft, timetotal, $element) {
  var progressBarWidth = timeleft * $element.width() / timetotal;
  $element.find('div').animate({
    width: progressBarWidth
  }, 500).html(Math.floor(timeleft / 60) + ":" + timeleft % 60);
  if (timeleft > 0) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      progress(timeleft - 1, timetotal, $element);
    }, 1000);
  }
};


$(document).ready(() => {
  console.log("loaded");
  $("#q-1").removeClass("hidden");
});


window.show = function show(id) {

            $("#q-1").addClass("hidden");
            $("#q-2").addClass("hidden");
            //$("q-3").addClass("hidden");


            $(`#q-${id}`).removeClass("hidden");

};
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#progressBar {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  height: 22px;
  background-color: #0A5F44;
}

#progressBar div {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0 10px;
  line-height: 22px;
  /* same as #progressBar height if we want text middle aligned */
  width: 0;
  background-color: #CBEA00;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Do not take in account */

html {
  padding-top: 30px
}

a.solink {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: #f3f5f6;
  color: #cfd6d9;
  border: 1px solid #cfd6d9;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all .3s;
  z-index: 999
}

a.solink::first-letter {
  text-transform: capitalize
}

a.solink:hover {
  color: #428bca
}


/* Create two unequal columns that floats next to each other */

.column {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}

.left {
  width: 75%;
  height: 100%;
}

.right {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* button */

.button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 2px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hidden{
display: none
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<div id="progressBar">
    <div class="bar"></div>
</div>

<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column left" style="background-color:#aaa;">
            <div id="q-1" class="hidden">
                <h2>Question 01</h2>
                <p>Full Form of HTML is "Hypertext Makrup Language"</p>
                <button onclick="truee()">True</button>
                <button onclick="falsee()">False</button>
            </div>
            <div id="q-2" class="hidden">
                <h2>Question 02</h2>
                <p>Full Form of HTML is "Hypertext Makrup Language"</p>
                <button onclick="truee()">True</button>
                <button onclick="falsee()">False</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column right" style="background-color:#bbb;">
            <h2>Questions</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="column right" style="background-color:#bbb;">
            <div>
                <button onclick="show(1)" class="button">01</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button onclick="show(2)" class="button">02</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this seem helpful ?

```js
$('.column.right:eq(-1) button').on('click', function() {
  let index = $(this).parent().index();
  $('.row .column.left div:eq("' + index + '")').show().siblings().hide();
})

$('.column.right:eq(-1) button:eq(0)').click();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#progressBar {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  height: 22px;
  background-color: #0A5F44;
}

#progressBar div {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0 10px;
  line-height: 22px;
  /* same as #progressBar height if we want text middle aligned */
  width: 0;
  background-color: #CBEA00;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Do not take in account */

html {
  padding-top: 30px
}

a.solink {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: #f3f5f6;
  color: #cfd6d9;
  border: 1px solid #cfd6d9;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all .3s;
  z-index: 999
}

a.solink::first-letter {
  text-transform: capitalize
}

a.solink:hover {
  color: #428bca
}


/* Create two unequal columns that floats next to each other */

.column {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}

.left {
  width: 75%;
  height: 100%;
}

.right {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* button */

.button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 2px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="progressBar">
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column left" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <div>
      <h2>Question 01</h2>
      <p>Full Form of HTML is "Hypertext Makrup Language"</p>
      <button onclick="truee()">True</button>
      <button onclick="falsee()">False</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2>Question 02</h2>
      <p>Full Form of HTML is "Hypertext Makrup Language"</p>
      <button onclick="truee()">True</button>
      <button onclick="falsee()">False</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column right" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Questions</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="column right list" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <div>
      <button class="button">01</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="button">02</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="button">03</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="button">04</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="button">05</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="button">06</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="button">07</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="button">08</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```